# Export With Box Spout

Tags: php, mysql, spout

I am trying to implement Box/Spout into a project of mine and I want to export some data.
The thing is that when I tried to make a test file to get downloaded it doesn't work, it's just a simple white page and the .xlsx download is not triggered.

Below is my code:

```
<?php

require_once 'vendor/box/spout/src/Spout/Autoloader/autoload.php';

use Box\Spout\Writer\Common\Creator\WriterEntityFactory;
use Box\Spout\Common\Entity\Row;

function xlsx(){
    $writer = WriterEntityFactory::createXLSXWriter();
    // $writer = WriterEntityFactory::createODSWriter();
    // $writer = WriterEntityFactory::createCSVWriter();
    $writer->setShouldUseInlineStrings(true); // default (and recommended) value

    $writer->setTempFolder($customTempFolderPath);

    $fileName = 'test.xlsx';

    // $writer->openToFile($filePath); // write data to a file or to a PHP stream
    $writer->openToBrowser($fileName); // stream data directly to the browser

    $cells = [
        WriterEntityFactory::createCell('Carl'),
        WriterEntityFactory::createCell('is'),
        WriterEntityFactory::createCell('great!'),
    ];

    /** add a row at a time */
    $singleRow = WriterEntityFactory::createRow($cells);
    $writer->addRow($singleRow);

    /** add multiple rows at a time */
    $multipleRows = [
        WriterEntityFactory::createRow($cells),
        WriterEntityFactory::createRow($cells),
    ];
    $writer->addRows($multipleRows); 

    /** Shortcut: add a row from an array of values */
    $values = ['Carl', 'is', 'great!'];
    $rowFromValues = WriterEntityFactory::createRowFromArray($values);
    $writer->addRow($rowFromValues);

    $writer->close();

}
```

This is a sample taken from the official documentation: https://opensource.box.com/spout/

Is there something I missed? What I am doing wrong?

Comment: You create a function `xlsx(){}` but you didin't start with that.

Answer (score -1):

It looks good to me. You just need to call the `xlsx()` function from your index.php to actually trigger the download.

To test if it really works, just move the contents of the `xlsx()` function directly inside index.php; that could help debug your issue